# Query for association that counts and returns lists with repeated elements

Tags: associations

I am trying to learn how Associations work differently from lists. I have read Seth Chandler's guide and all the documentation. What I do easily in lists seems to elude me when I use an Association. Here is a list of lists

```
list = {{"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"}, {"a", 15, "c", "d"}, {"e", 
9, "f", "g"}, {"h", "cat", "d", "s"}, {"dog", "cat", "owl", 
"ferret"}, {"stove", "refrig", "dish", "fork"}, {"land", "water", 
"sea", "fire"}, {"if", 15, "and", "but"}, {"either", 9, "or", 
"maybe"}, {"w", "x", "y", "z"}, {"in", "cat", "out", "with"}};
```

This makes the list of lists an Association

```
 listToAssociation[data : {__List}, head___List, 
      OptionsPattern[{"headers" -> True}]] :=
        If[OptionValue["headers"]
           , Inner[Rule, data[[1]], #, Association] & /@ data[[2 ;; All]]
           , Inner[Rule, head, #, Association] & /@ data[[2 ;; All]]
         ];
     assocTest = listToAssociation[list, "headers" -> True];
```

And this groups by col2

```
q1 = Query[GroupBy[#col2 &]][assocTest]
```

Note that the second element in each list (column 2) has repeated values (9 and 15 each appear twice and "cat" appears three times)

I need a query that chooses those lists having duplicate elements in them, counts the number of times each duplicate appears. Using lists, this kludge produces output that works

```
 countFct[list_List] := Module[{dups, cnt},
   dups = Select[GatherBy[Drop[list, 1], #[[2]] &], Length[#] > 1 &];
cnt = Length[dups[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[dups]];
   Grid[Transpose[{cnt, dups}], Frame -> All]
   ];
```

which looks like this

[image]

Association is supposed to make this a lot easier. I have not found that to be so, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does use associations, but in a roundabout way, i.e. mostly because that's the output of [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html). The real advantage is the fact that `GroupBy` also allows the use of a combiner function that operates on each of the groups; we can take advantage of that to post-process groups and mark those without repeated entries for removal.

```
GroupBy[
  Rest@list,
  #[[2]] &,
  Block[{len = Length[#]},
    If[len > 1, {len, #}, Nothing]
  ] &
] // Values // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image: same grid of results as OP]

I am not sure that I can see a more straight forward way to use association objects directly here. I also wanted to note that your `listToAssociation` function returns a list of associations, rather than a single Association object. I am not sure that a list of associations would have many advantages over a plain list of lists.